# Ninject Authorization vs Action Filter binding order

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, action-filter, authorize-attribute, custom-action-filter

I have 2 filters I'm trying to apply using Ninject's `BindFilter<>` syntax, and they are being applied with their dependency injection successfully. The problem lies in the fact that the one sorts out who the current user is and binds that `InRequestScope`, and has to run before the second one when checking for maintenance authorization - otherwise it doesn't know which user you're referring to.

The filter binding in `NinjectWebCommon.cs` looks like this:

```
kernel.BindFilter<CurrentUserFilter>(FilterScope.Global, 0).InRequestScope();
kernel.BindFilter<SetupRightsAttribute>(FilterScope.Controller, 1).WhenControllerType<MaintenanceController>().InRequestScope();
```

So in the Maintenance controller, I'm wanting the first one to run and then the second; in everything else just the first one - and this works, the second one is only used when browsing to something in my Maintenance controller.

The 2 filters are declared as such (irrelevant details excluded)

```
public class CurrentUserFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    // implementation - breakpoint 1
}

public class SetupRightsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    // implementation - breakpoint 2
}
```

I'm expecting breakpoint 1 to be hit and then breakpoint 2, but for some reason it's *always* breakpoint 2 first - and because it doesn't know the user at this point it tells me I have no authorization.

I have tried many different permutations of FilterScope and order settings, even binding them in a different order, but nothing works...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authorization filters are executed before action filters, because authorization is earlier in the MVC execution pipeline than processing the action.

Comment: Thanks Remo, I'll change it to an action filter then...or something along those lines :-P